# why is my plivo api call returning an error?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, plivo

I am using the plivo search number api to list telephone numbers by selected parameters.

The ruby code is:

```
get '/search_numbers' do
p = RestAPI.new(AUTH_ID, AUTH_TOKEN)
      params = {'country_iso' => 'GB'}
      response = p.search_phone_number(params)
end
```

and the error I receive is:

```
88.106.106.78 - - [22/Jan/2015:15:02:59 +0000] "GET /search_numbers HTTP/1.0" 200 - 1.7485
2015-01-22 15:02:59 +0000: Read error: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `bytesize' for ["api_id", "c025f0cc-a247-11e4-b153-22000abcaa64"]:Array>
```

I simply cannot figure out what is wrong. I can see no typos, the parameter that is passed is correct and in the correct format and the function is the right function to use.

Help, please!

Comment: Looks (superficially) like a bug in the implementation of either `RestAPI` or `search_phone_number`, but it's hard to tell with only the error message and not the stack trace indicating what file/line is causing that error.

Comment: cheers Phrogz, sorry to trouble you. In fact I needed to update the gem because they had made changes to the api. Hmm, no prizes to me for that.

Comment: I suggest that you post your own answer with the information on the old version and new version. Others may encounter this same issue, and your information could help them.